# How do I create a new directory from within ranger?

Tags: ranger

I have recently moved from *dired* to *ranger*.
While using it on a regular work day, I noticed there isn't any command for creating a new directory.

Is there a workaround or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming this is talking about the https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el package available from [Melpa](http://melpa.org/packages).
There are several things you can do

1. Use "!" to run a command. This is made slightly tricky as ranger seems to want to pass the filename you are on to the command, so something like `mkdir wibble ; :` could be used on unix systems.
2. Switch to dired mode using `control-p`, then use `+` to call `dired-create-directory`, and then `control-p` to switch back to ranger
3. Add

   ```
   (require 'ranger)
   (define-key ranger-normal-mode-map (kbd "+") #'dired-create-directory)
   ```

to your startup file.

Whilst ranger is quite pretty, I dislike the way it takes away standard ways to discover things. In particular binding control-h to toggle hidden (dot) files is bad.

Comment: Also learnt you can do it with `; +`

Answer (score 1):

To create a new directory you can use either of the two commands (Ranger v1.7.2-1 on Arch Linux):

```
F7

:mkdir
```

You can also assign your custom hotkey by editing file

```
~/.config/ranger/rc.conf
```

Comment: I think you are talking about ranger as a stand-alone program, rather than https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el which is a piece of emacs lisp code which gives you a similar interface.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is `dired-create-directory` (bound by default to <kbd>+</kbd> in `dired`). It will prompt you for the name of the directory to create.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please note that the [accepted answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28473) and related comment already provide this information.